# Firefox permission to URL doesn't work in browser extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I created Chrome extension and it works as I expected. Actually, it periodically sends http request to my server.  But when I tried to run it in Firefox, I've got such an error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at <my_server_ip>:8080/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

My application listens for incoming requests at server_ip:8080
For making requests to my server from chrome extension, I add such entry to manifest.json:

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://server_ip:8080/*"
  ],
```

Suddenly, it doesn't work in Firefox and I can't understand why.
I tried a workaround (found in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)):

```
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

And the problem with CORS disappeared. But I want to give permissions only to my resourse - server_ip:8080

How I need to put a rule in permissions entry to make extension work in Firefox?

Comment: Port numbers aren't necessary there (all ports are valid), see https://crbug.com/71531 and [Match port in Chrome extension pattern](//stackoverflow.com/a/11425751)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on wOxxOm's comment you only need this for your URL permission

```
"permissions": [
    "http://server_ip/*"
],
```

Comment: Awesome! This drove me nuts and wasted a lot of time. The documentation even explictly states that `host must not include a port number`. It's easy to overlook and should be more prominent, e.g. there should have been an example in the "Invalid Matches" section of the documentations. For more details see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#host