# Sending POST request to local service in the content script in an add-on

Tags: firefox-addon

I don't know if this is possible, but I want to send a POST request to a local service in the content script of my private add-on.

I tried to send the request with `XMLHttpRequest`, but it failed due to cross-origin restriction:

`` Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8089/... (Reason: CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). ``

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions) that I could specify extra match patterns to allow cross-origin access in content scripts, but the restriction was still in effect after adding `"http://127.0.0.1:8089/*"` to `permissions` in `manifest.json`.

Is it possible to overcome the cross-origin restriction? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [wOxxOm's comment under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850733/firefox-permission-to-url-doesnt-work-in-browser-extension), port numbers should not appear in match patterns.

I changed the pattern in my `manifest.json` to `http://127.0.0.1/*` and the request could be sent successfully.